# Optimization of simple algorithm

Tags: ruby, loops

I have this problem:

> Given the lengths of laps run by two joggers (at the same speed), return the #number of laps. Each must run before they arrive at the starting point at the same #time.

and this code:

```
def nbr_of_laps(x, y)
  result = []
  lcm = 1
  until lcm % x == 0 || lcm % y == 0
    lcm +=1
  end
  result << (lcm/x, lcm/y)
  return result 
end
```

This takes more than 12 seconds to execute. Can you tell me what is so inefficient about this code?

Comment: I'm very new to ruby, so I'm not sure about the timing issue, but your `until` is definitely incorrect. It should be `&&` (boolean "and"), not `||` (boolean "or"). That's what a least common multiple is.

Comment: You must be dealing with relatively large numbers (for small numbers this is instant*), and thus the inefficiency is from incrementing and checking one at a time. There are a number of ways to improve this...searching for Least Common Multiple algorithms, will give you several good ways to go

Comment: `(lcm/x, lcm/y)` is not a valid Ruby expression. Do you mean `[lcm/x, lcm/y]`? If you believe your code works always check before posting. It is not meaningful to say that it takes 12 seconds to solve without giving the associated values of `x` and `y`. Suppose those values are `1` and `2`?

Comment: I hadn't noticed all your work is to compute the lowest common multiple. Ruby's Integer class has such a method, saving you the trouble of reinventing the wheel (unless this is an exercise and you are not permitted to use that built-in method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let d1 and d2 be positive integers that equal the lengths of a lap for runners 1 and 2, respectively, and let s be the speed at which both run. Without loss of generality, assume s = 1.

At time t = d1*d2, runner 1 has completed (d1*d2*s)/d1 = d2 laps and runner 2 has completed (d1*d2*s)/d2 = d1 laps. Since d1, d2 and s are both positive integers, both cross the finish line at this time t.

Let n equal the least common multiple of d1 and d2. Then d1 = n1*n and d2 = n2*n, where n1, n2 and n are all positive integers. Now at time t = n runner 1 has completed d1/n = n1 laps and runner 2 has completed d2/n = n2 laps. Since n1 and n2 are both positive integers, this is an upper bound on the time at which both runners cross the finish line. (Note that `n <= d1*d2`.)

Now suppose there is a time t, t < n, at which both players cross the finish line. Then runner 1 completes t/d1 laps and runner 2 completes t/d2 laps. However, because t is not a multiple of both d1 and d2 (since it is less than the least common multiple of those numbers), a contradiction is established (i.e., that both runners complete an integral number of laps at time t is shown to be false). We therefore conclude that the least common multiple of d1 and d2 is the first time both runners cross the finish line at the same time.

This is of course trivial to implement.

```
def nbr_laps(d1, d2)
  t = d1.lcm(d2)
  { player1: t/d1, player2: t/d2 }
end

nbr_laps(1, 2)              #=> {:player1=>2, :player2=>1}         lcm = 2
nbr_laps(2, 6)              #=> {:player1=>3, :player2=>1}         lcm = 3
nbr_laps(12, 60)            #=> {:player1=>5, :player2=>1}         lcm = 5
nbr_laps(132, 164)          #=> {:player1=>41, :player2=>33}       lcm = 5412
nbr_laps(123_456, 345_678)  #=> {:player1=>57613, :player2=>20576} lcm = 7112670528
```

See [Integer#lcm](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm).